# Expand google maps' visible region

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, markerclusterer

I am using ClusterManager from Google to render a lot of places in a map. The problem is I might have up to 5000+ places so the cluster renderer becomes extremely slow, sometimes it takes more than a second to expand or collapse a cluster while the old cluster result is still visible on the screen.

So in order to optimize I want to show only those markers visible to the user. For that I take my marker list and filter those markers outside of the visible region of my map.

However this causes reclustering when spanning the map, which is an odd effect. I would like then to filter those places in a visible region around 150% bigger than the actual one.

How can I calculate this region from the [VisibleRegion](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/VisibleRegion) object I get from the Google Maps API?

Comment: While I think you are better off solving your clustering issues (post your configuration), to answer your question compute the differentials between the n-s and w-e dimensions of visible region - multiply by a scalar (1.11 to increase by 50%) and add to respective corners. (This is 150% the size - not 150% bigger) - and it has some error in it since this is geodesic space. Of course you'd have to do this on every map adjustment.

Comment: @Andy its slow even using the default renderer. I've seen it as a common problem so I guess the cluster library is just not too performant

Comment: I use this library for clustering and works great: https://github.com/mg6maciej/android-maps-extensions (based on v2)

Comment: Mmm did not know about this will try it!